# RMarkdown render to Notebook with child chunks included

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, knitr-spin

I'm after a way to render an Rmd document (that contains references to various "child" files) to a *self-contained* R Notebook without these dependencies.

At the moment, the .Rmd code chunks are located throughout a number of .R, .py and .sql files and are referenced in the report using

````
```{r extraction, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk("myscript.R")
```
````

followed by

````
```{r chunk_from_myscript}
```
````

as documented [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/).

I've done this to avoid code duplication and to allow for running the source files separately however these code chunks are only executable in the report via a call to `knit` or `render` (when `read_chunk` is run and the code chunk is available).

Is there a way to spin-off an Rmd (prior to knitting) with
just these chunks populated?

This function

```
rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", clean = FALSE)
```

almost gets there as it leaves the markdown files behind whilst removing `extraction` and populating `chunk_from_myscript` however as these files are straight markdown, the chunks are no longer executable and the chunk options are missing. It obviously also doesn't include chunks where `eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE` which would be needed to run the resulting notebook.

I've also looked at `knitr::spin` however this would mean disseminating the contents of the report to every source file and isn't terribly ideal.

## Reprex

report.Rmd

````
---
title: 'Report'
---

```{r read_chunks, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk("myscript.R")
```

Some documentation

```{r chunk_from_myscript}
```

Some more documentation

```{r chunk_two_from_myscript, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
```
````

myscript.R

```
#' # MyScript
#' 
#' This is a valid R source file which is formatted
#' using the `knitr::spin` style comments and code
#' chunks.
#' The file's code can be used in large .Rmd reports by
#' extracting the various chunks using `knitr::read_chunk` or
#' it can be spun into its own small commented .Rmd report
#' using `knitr::spin`

# ---- chunk_from_myscript
sessionInfo()

#' This is the second chunk

# ---- chunk_two_from_myscript
1 + 1
```

**Desired Output**

notebook.Rmd

````
---
title: 'Report'
---

Some documentation

```{r chunk_from_myscript}
sessionInfo()
```

Some more documentation

```{r chunk_two_from_myscript, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
1 + 1
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Working through your `reprex` I now better understand the issue you are trying to solve. You can `knit` into an *output.Rmd* to merge your report and scripts into a single markdown file.

Instead of using `knitr::read_chunk`, I've read in with `knitr::spin` to `cat` the `asis` output into another `.Rmd` file. Also note the `params$final` flag to allow rendering the final document when set as `TRUE` or allowing the `knit` to an intermediate `.Rmd` as `FALSE` by default.

#### report.Rmd

````
---
title: "Report"
params:
  final: false
---

```{r load_chunk, include=FALSE}
chunk <- knitr::spin(text = readLines("myscript.R"), report = FALSE, knit = params$final)
```


Some documentation

```{r print_chunk, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(chunk, sep = "\n")
```
````

to produce the intermediate file:

```
rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", "output.Rmd")
```

#### output.Rmd

````
---
title: "Report"
---

Some documentation

```{r chunk_from_myscript, echo=TRUE}
sessionInfo() 
```
````

With the secondary `output.Rmd`, you could continue with my original response below to render to `html_notebook` so that the document may be shared without needing to regenerate but still containing the source R markdown file.

To render the final document from `report.Rmd` you can use:

```
rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", params = list(final = TRUE))
```

#### Original response

You need to include additional arguments to your `render` statement.

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "output.Rmd",
  output_format = "html_notebook",
  output_file = "output.nb.html"
)
```

When you open the `.nb.html` file in *RStudio* the embedded `.Rmd` will be viewable in the editing pane.

Comment: Interestingly the embedded file is still the old "unpopulated" `.Rmd` yet the `.nb.html` shows the fully compiled and populated code.

Comment: @ruaridhw, if this is not helpful to you, please provide a `reprex`. You have conflicting statements in your question about not knitting but to include child document information.

Comment: Sorry, reprex added. The child documents are the source files however it looks as though these cannot be separated from the knitting process. The output from your example is the notebook html but the embedded `.Rmd` is still the old `report.Rmd`.

Comment: @ruaridhw, now edited to resolve the two-step final render

Comment: thanks for the extensive help on this. I'm not able to reproduce your **output.Rmd** file using the code `rmarkdown::render("report.Rmd", output_file = "output.Rmd")` because the default output is HTML. Did you mean to call `knitr::knit` instead?

Comment: This is a pretty valid solution for `.R` files with only one (large) chunk however I should have been clearer that the reprex I gave was *minimal*; `myscript.R` actually contains many chunks, hence the need for `read_chunk` over `spin(text = read_lines)`

Comment: @ruaridhw, I accept that my solution is sub-optimal for a script containing many chunks. However, it is entirely possible for you to extend to suit multiple chunks, just read in the R script, split into chunks and assign those values to your various locations.

Answer (score 0):

Since neither `knitr::knit` nor `rmarkdown::render` seem suited to rendering **to** R markdown, I've managed to somewhat work around this by dynamically inserting the chunk text into each empty chunk and writing that to a new file:

````
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# Find the line numbers of every empty code chunk
get_empty_chunk_line_nums <- function(file_text){
  # Create an Nx2 matrix where the rows correspond
  # to code chunks and the columns are start/end line nums
  mat <- file_text %>%
    grep(pattern = "^```") %>%
    matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  # Return the chunk line numbers where the end line number
  # immediately follows the starting line (ie. chunk is empty)
  empty_chunks <- mat[,1] + 1 == mat[,2]
  mat[empty_chunks, 1]
}

# Substitute each empty code chunk with the code from `read_chunk`
replace_chunk_code <- function(this_chunk_num) {
  this_chunk <- file_text[this_chunk_num]
  # Extract the chunk alias
  chunk_name <- stringr::str_match(this_chunk, "^```\\{\\w+ (\\w+)")[2]
  # Replace the closing "```" with "<chunk code>\n```"
  chunk_code <- paste0(knitr:::knit_code$get(chunk_name), collapse = "\n")
  file_text[this_chunk_num + 1] %<>% {paste(chunk_code, ., sep = "\n")}
  file_text
}

render_to_rmd <- function(input_file, output_file, source_files) {
  lapply(source_files, knitr::read_chunk)
  file_text <- readLines(input_file)
  empty_chunks <- get_empty_chunk_line_nums(file_text)
  for (chunk_num in empty_chunks){
    file_text <- replace_chunk_code(file_text, chunk_num)
  }
  writeLines(file_text, output_file)
}

source_files <- c("myscript.R")
render_to_rmd("report.Rmd", "output.Rmd", source_files)
````

This has the added benefits of preserving chunk options and working
with Python and SQL chunks too since there is no requirement to evaluate
any chunks in this step.